# Suppose $\alpha$ is an irrational number, and if $f(x)=ax+b, a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and that $f(\alpha) \not= 0$, prove that $ab \not=0.$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Suppose $\alpha$ is an irrational number, and if $f(x)=ax+b, a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and that $f(\alpha) \not= 0$, prove that $ab \not=0.$ I think we have to use the rational root theorem but I cant solve it, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Not true: let $a=1, b=0, \alpha=\pi$. Clearly $f(\alpha)=\pi\neq 0$ and $ab=0$.